# Where lies the soul of a computer?

Tags: hostname

When you take the system drive and put it in a new box, do you rename it or do you keep the name? And when you put a fresh drive in the old box, do you give it a new name? What is with upgrading? How many of the components do you have to change until a computer loses its identity?

So a CPU is often described as the heart or the brain of a computer but where lies its soul? What determines its identity? The data on the system drive? The majority of its components?

This might sound like a not-so-serious question and it probably is but whom of you didn't already face this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I hereby declare, and it shall be forever so:

## The powersupply.

Answer (score 0):

Per MS, this algorithm is used to determine whether an OEM install is the "same" computer it was initially sold on: http://www.aumha.org/win5/a/wpa.php . are you having trouble activating a windows instance after a Mobo replace?

personally a computer "is" what it does. when I rebuild a server, install the services it previously had and restore the data those services require, I consider it a new build of the same computer. think of it like a human changing clothes. each build is a differant pair of trousers. On a hardware level, everything is peripheral except the Mobo. CPUs and everything else can be swapped out, and that's just upgrades.